# Append PDF to existing PDF stored on Sharepoint site?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, pdf

Is there any functionality/add-ons in Sharepoint 2013 to allow for a PDF to be appended to the end of an existing PDF stored on a Sharepoint site. I.e. can the append be completed during upload? This will save me from having to check out the existing PDF, add the page with Acrobat, then check in the file.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-built functionality in SharePoint to do this.

There are add-ons such as [Plumsail](https://plumsail.com/blog/2014/11/generate-pdf-document-using-workflow-sharepoint-2013-office-365/) or [Muhimbi](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint.aspx) which will let you generate PDFs from other artifacts as a part of a workflow. So you could possibly build a workflow that would regenerate PDFs from other information in SharePoint as required.

Comment: For completeness, you can find the PDF Merge facilities for the mentioned Muhimbi product at http://support.muhimbi.com/entries/23752263-What-PDF-merging-facilities-are-available

Answer (score 0):

At some point that I had to do a similar task I ended up using [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/).
(and a lot of code of course...)